# How to move the cursor to the beginning of the next line on a .txt file?

Tags: delphi, text-files, delphi-2007

I am writing a function with which, I'm trying to load saved data from a file to an array of records. The file is going to contain a name of the type of data I want to read. After that initial line every next line, until the end of the current type of data, will be a line of data that I need to fill into the array of records. Since I'm going to have different types of data lines, I don't want to iterate through the whole file, but I want to go straight to the lines I need to take data from. I have another function `CheckTXTFileForDataName` that searches if the data type exists in the file and returns an array of records, that returns a boolean, which value is based on whether the data type is in the file and it also returns the line at which the data type was found at, as an integer.

This is my code, with which I'm trying to load the data (Note: The function isn't finished, because I need to figure how to move the cursor first)

```
function LoadArrayFromTXTFile(const dataArray : array of TdataRecord; const arrayName : string) : TResultArray;
var
  txtFile : TextFile;
  txtFilePath, fileLine : string;
  i : integer;
begin
  txtFilePath := GetFilePath('Date Arrays\DataArrays.txt');

  AssignFile(txtFile, txtFilePath);

  if FileExists(txtFilePath) then
  begin
    Reset(txtFile);
  end;

  ReadLn(txtFile, fileLine);
  Delete(fileLine, Pos(' |', fileLine), (Length(fileLine) - Pos('|', fileLine) + 1));

  if CheckTXTFileForDataName(dataArray, arrayName)[0].nameIsInFile then
  begin                                                                              
    for I := 0 to Length(ReaderArray) - 1 do
    begin
      ReadLn(txtFile, fileLine);

      Result[i].keycode := StrToInt(Copy(fileLine, 1, (Pos(',', fileLine) - 1)));
      Result[i].shiftState := Copy(fileLine, Pos(' ', fileLine) + 1, Length(fileLine) - Pos(' ', fileLine));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

As you can see in the second `if statement` I'm reading a line from a text file and then I assign the data values to where I need them. My question is, can I, and if yes, how to change the cursor to a specific line of the file?
As I already mentioned `CheckTXTFileForDataName(dataArray, arrayName)` has a second variable in it, which is the variable `lineNumber` with which I keep the line where the data starts, meaning if the `lineNumber` is 56, then I need to start reading from 57th line.

Here's an example of how the .txt file would look like with the names of the variables for you to understand what I'm saving(in brackets in what types I would be loading the data):

```
KeycodesArrayName(string) | KeycodeCount(integer)
keycode(word), shiftState(boolean)
keycode(word), shiftState(boolean)
.
.
.
keycode(word), shiftState(boolean)
```

KeycodesArrayName is the name with which I think of distinguishing the different saves of data. KeycodeCount is the amount of keycodes saved(also the amount of lines which I need to take after the correct data name). Keycode and shiftState are self-explanatory.

Here's an example with values:

```
FirstArray | 58
48, false
53, false
76, true
.
.
.
72, false
```

In this situation, if I want the data from FirstArray(I will name them better, this is a name just for the example), I will check if it exists in the file, and if yes, I'd save the amount of keycodeCount, which is 58, which means that I need the next 58 lines. Then the keycodes are just going to be saved as they are, not with Char() or anything like that, and same goes with shiftState, no changes there either.

Comment: You can't jump to a specific line unless you know its exact byte offset in the file. If you have that, you can use `Seek()` for that purpose. However, it appears you have a line number instead of a byte offset, so the only way you can jump to a specific line is to read all previous lines until you reach the desired line (assuming all of your lines are not the same length). While your `CheckTXTFileForDataName()` function is scanning the file, it can use `FilePos()` before reading a new line to get that line's byte offset.

Comment: @RemyLebeau oh, okay. Thanks for the response. I will look into the Seek() function and see how it works. If I think I can implement it into the code I will change my other function and see if I can get the exact byte offset of the line in the file and work with it.

Comment: Use ``TStringList.LoadFromFile``

Comment: @DelphiCoder Using of `TStringList` might seem an easy solution since it can automatically split any text file into individual lines.  Now the problem is that in order to do this it needs to load entire file into memory. So if OP is working with very large files he might be running into memory issues.

Comment: @DelphiCoder thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it as well.

Comment: @SilverWarior Actually the file won't be that big. I expect 200-500 lines which isn't that big of a problem. But since I'm learning to code I wanted to know if there is a more optimal way, where I don't read every single line, because in the future I'm sure I will have to read bigger files

Comment: Would you mind showing us an example of data structure in this TXT file you are working with. Maybe we could recognize the data structure and point you to an already made solution for such file type or at least try to work on our own example.

Comment: @SilverWarior done

Comment: What are you working here with? Is this an output of some keyloger?

Comment: @SilverWarior I know the possible drawbacks you mentioned, I'm not a newbie. But for a beginner this is a very simple solution. Oh, and I should have mentioned ``TFile.ReadAllText`` from ``System.IOUtils``